# How to finely manage an isolated scope in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to have a scope in javascript where I can run code and which has no visibility to my local scope.

**main.js**

```
const isolated = require('./isolated.js');
function f() {return "a";} // invisible by the isolated scope
isolated.eval('function f() {return "b";}'); // invisible by my local scope
let b = isolated.eval("f();"); // I could get the result however
console.log(b); // "b"
```

A solution with modules would be perfect. But is it even possible?

**isolated.js**

```
module.exports = {
    eval: ???
}
```

My best option so far has been to generate a temp file, execute it with [process.fork()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) and get results from log file. But I'm looking for a something lightweight and on which my `main.js` can have fine control.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Like something like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval`?

Comment: @Derek: interesting, I have to check this: *Be careful about the objects you are passing to the context API*. Also, it forgets context on subsequent calls?

Comment: Yeah, so the context is supposed to be its only knowledge of the current "state", which is really just the object you pass it.

Comment: Just loading a file as a nodejs module will have no visibility to your local scope (it will have access to your global scope).  You can also use an indirect reference to `eval()` to execute it in the global scope so code run by `eval()` has no access to your local scope as [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: @jfriend00: I chose [safe-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval) which does what you describe. If you want to try my test framework: https://github.com/RaphaelSaban/jfest. Hope you like it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have a somewhat hacky method of solving this issue, but it might work for your purposes. Instead of having a single eval function in isolated, you could have one that declares a variable/function, and the other that calls your previously declared variable/function. You can keep track of the declarations in a local dictionary that you append to your eval in the call function. Something like this:

**isolated.js**

```
var isolatedFunctions = {};

module.exports.declare = function(strName, strContents) {
    isolatedFunctions[strName] = eval(`(${strContents})`);
}

module.exports.call = function (strCall) {
    return eval(`(isolatedFunctions.${strCall})`);
}
```

You would then use it like this:

**main.js**

```
const isolated = require("./isolated.js");
function f() { return "a" }
isolated.declare ("f", "function() { return 'b' }");
var b = isolated.call("f()");
var a = f(); 
console.log(a); // Outputs "a"
console.log(b); // Outputs "b"
```

There are a few obvious limitations to this, the main being that you  have to be very specific with the way that you call a function, because in order to accommodate the possibility of parameters, it just prepends "isolatedFunctions." in the `eval` call.

There is very likely a better way to accomplish what you're looking for, but I figured I would share this possibility in case it suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Keveloper, I'll give it a try and compare with [save-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval)